# trying to find a inner product.

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a hilbertspace, and let $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a ortonormal basis for the hilbertspace. Let a x,y $ \in \mathcal{H}$ and set: 
$$ <x,e_k> = \frac{1}{2^k} \qquad <y,e_k> =(-1)^k \frac{1}{2^k}$$ for all k $\in \mathbb{N}$

Calculated $\mid \mid x \mid \mid, \mid \mid y \mid \mid, <x,y>  $

I calculated $\mid \mid x \mid \mid, \mid \mid y \mid \mid $ both to $ \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$
But my problem is the last one.

I was trying to use parcivals identity, but then i need $<e_k,y>$ i can't se how to find that. Can anybody help to how to tackle this?

Comment: An infinite-dimensional Hilbert space doesn't possess  a countable basis ...

Comment: It seems that you do not know the notion "orthonormal basis" ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$<x,y>=\sum_{k=1}^\infty<x,e_k> \overline{<y,e_k>}$,

since $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty<x,e_k>e_k$ and $y=\sum_{k=1}^\infty<y,e_k>e_k$

FRED

Comment: As i understand it, i should be able to calculate a number.

Comment: I don't exactly see how, that can be used. The upper equation is the one, I tried to use but i can't seem to find $ <e_k,y>$ could you elaborate?

Comment: $<e_k,y>=<y,e_k>$, since $<y,e_k>$ is real.